# Why printing '10'?

Tags: c++, arduino

I wrote a program for char to decimal below, and I don't know why it printing '10' in between.

```
int variable;

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
    if(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        variable = Serial.read();

        Serial.println(variable);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to receive data as `char`, you need to cast it to char like `char c = (char) Serial.read()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`10` is `\n` in ASCII which is `println` very likely appending to the output in each call.

Use `Serial.print` to only print the number.

Comment: Using Serial.println is good, but the OP just needs to not *send* any newline characters when sending data to the Arduino.  This is done by correctly configuring the Serial Monitor or whatever serial terminal program the OP is using.

Comment: I'd think the newline being in the input is the more likely culprit

Comment: @AlanBirtles Oh, yea, I got it reversed... feel free to make it an answer.